# StringBuilder string format

Tags: c#

```
scriptValues.AppendFormat("something = {1};", SessionID.ToString());
```

in the above, I get a R# warning or something that says I need to add a 3rd param.  When I look with intellisense it shows string formatter.  Do I need one here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be scriptValues.AppendFormat(@"something = {0}";", SessionID.ToString());